# python hash function with same hash value

Tags: python, hash

I have a python hash function and I am trying to get 10 key with same hash value but I can't find out.

Here is my function:

```
import math
def h(x):
    return math.floor((2**14)*((x*2654435769.0/(2**32)) %1))
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do. Example input and expected output.

Comment: In your code, you are doing mod 1 which makes no sense at all as it will always result in 0.  You are also multiplying by the result.  Based on the code in your block there you might as well just be returning 0 which makes no sense.  If you are trying to find multiple values which would result in the same hash value this would completely depend on what hash function you are using.  Any commonly used hash function is pretty much designed to prevent (a collision) this without massive amounts of computation time.

Comment: I can take some integer inputs like 1,5,10,11. Actually any number would be fine. If I use h() to deal with number x and y and they are same that is h(x) == h(y), then they have same hash value. I need to find 10 numbers that h(x) == h(y) == h(z) == h(a) == h(b) etc. find out value for x,y,z,a,b etc.

Comment: I'm doing x*2654435769.0 so that we can have float number with decimals. Here is a example:                                                                       >>> map(h, range(10))
[0.0, 10125.0, 3867.0, 13993.0, 7735.0, 1477.0, 11603.0, 5345.0, 15470.0, 9212.0]

Comment: So as I said... you are multiplying the result of mod 1  ( %1) which is 0.  This means your result is ALWAYS going to be 0 if your input is an integer.  Therefore your answer is any integer has the same result.

Comment: @Goblinlord: Take a look at what happens when you do `%1` to a float.

Comment: umm, I mean, if we take a decimal number then mod 1 we can get the decimal part. Such as 2.53 % 1 == .53

Comment: @Nick: FWIW, you can speed up that hash function by pre-defining your constants instead of computing them _every_ time you call the function. You can find collisions by feeding random x's to the function and storing the results in a dict of lists, with the hash value as the dict key and the x's stored in the lists. BTW, are your x's integers or floats?

Comment: `[121320548, 1669539634, 758468482, 162625121, 399806761, 1321640923, 46387441, 1742586170, 971412256, 328103910]` all hash to 3010

Comment: I am totally lost on how you came up with these as this function returns a 0 for me no matter what I put in it.  If you need something as a float you can cast it as a float.  Either way, I did say mod 1 will return 0 "if your input is an integer".  Also, even if the inner function returns a anything between 0-1 then math.floor will always return 0 as it returns an integer as a float.  I am obviously missing something. =/

Comment: @Goblinlord: In Nick's function, the `%1` is being applied to a float (to be specific, x/phi). For float u `u%1` is equivalent to `u - floor(u)`. I don't know why Nick's `h(x)` returns 0 for you, maybe it's a Python 3 thing - I'm using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah =/... I missed a parentheses.  I got it now.  I wasn't able to copy+paste and I was doing it incorrectly.

Comment: This is your second of three "do my homework for me" question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your hash function to return an `int` instead of a `float`. And I've pre-defined the constants so they don't need to be computed every time the function is called.

(**edit** The pre-defining of the constants may not be strictly necessary, Python's constant folding may look after that for us.)

We find collisions by feeding random x's to the function and storing the results in a dict of lists, with the hash value as the dict key and the x's stored in the lists. To keep the code simple, I've used a defaultdict, but the code could easily be modified to use a standard dict.

The code below can find a list of 10 colliding keys in a couple of seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math
import random
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

k14 = 1 << 14
phibar = 2654435769.0 / (1 << 32)

def h(x):
    return int(math.floor(k14 * ((x * phibar) % 1)))

#random.seed(163)

hi = sys.maxint
rand = random.randint

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(100000):
    x = rand(0, hi)
    v = h(x)
    d[v].append(x)
    if len(d[v]) == 10:
        print i
        print v, d[v]
        break
```

**typical output**

```
26580
4695 [2117596615, 363105812, 629092494, 1450847021, 749292969, 1735204492, 21338856, 1153043351, 1047107585, 138752460]
```